# Restructuring hierarchy of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary with 3 level hierarchy. For Example:

```
d = { 'week': {'year': {'zone': 'val'}}}
```

where zone, week and year are respective keys in nested dictionary.

I am having problem in restructuring it as:

```
d_new = {'zone': {'week': {'year': 'val'}}}
```

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reshape(d):
    new_d = {}
    for z, w, y, v in [(z, w, y, d[w][y][z]) for w in d.keys() for y in d[w].keys() for z in d[w][y].keys()]:
        if z not in new_d.keys(): new_d[z] = {}
        if w not in new_d[z].keys(): new_d[z][w] = {}
        new_d[z][w][y] = v
    return new_d

d = {"w": {"y": {"z": "val"}}}
new_d = reshape(d)
print(d)  # {'z': {'w': {'y': 'val'}}}
```

Comment: Not quite understanding why [week, year, zone] are separate keys though. Could simply have (week, year, zone) as one key.

Comment: It was made like this in designing of software. I was trying to use defaultdict in this solution but stuck at how to approach at this problem. Thanks a lot.